# Can we add syntax highlighting to the Q# tag?

Tags: feature-request

for [q#](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/q%23), would it be possible to add csharp syntax highlighting? For now, I have been editing codeblocks in the posts as follows:

````
```csharp
````

but it would be nice if this was done autotmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the pointer. I've changed the default language of posts tagged with `q#` into C-sharp. Let me know if that works fine.

Comment: Yup, seems to be working fine now. Thanks!